# error: class is not a template

Tags: c++, class, templates, typename

I have the following class:

```
#include "SingleNode.h"

template <typename T>
class LinkedList<T>
{
    private:
        SingleNode<T>* head;
        SingleNode<T>* tail;
        SingleNode<T>* current;
        int currentSize;

    public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();
};
```

As far as I can tell there isn't anything wrong with it. However, the compiler is giving me the following:

```
error: 'LinkedList' is not a template
```

Why isn't the compiler recognizing it as a template?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the `<T>` from the declaration:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
```